# Why do I get empty string from req.body.newItem?

Tags: express, post, ejs

Github repo: https://github.com/tomkovladko/goormProblem

*I posted my Todolist App(from Colt's lecture on Udemy) on Goorm and everything works just fine except one thing.*

**I tried to make a POST method so that if you press enter it goes to /addItem and creates and add new `<li>` to the body.**

that unfortunately doesn't work and i just get this:

```
{ newItem: '' }
```

I compared it to PostRequestDemo that Colt did and it's almost the same code, here:

*Mine*

```
app.post("/newItem", function(req,res){
    var newItem = req.body.newItem
    console.log(newItem)     #here is where i get the empty string... it should print something i inputed to the form (for example "banana")
       res.redirect("/")
})   
---------------------
    <form action="/newItem" method="POST"> 
        <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="Add New Todo">
    </form>
```

*Colt's*

```
app.post("/addFriend", function(req, res){
    var newFriend = req.body.newFriend
    friends.push(newFriend)
    res.redirect("friends")
})
---------------------
<form method="POST" action="/addFriend">
    <input type="text" name="newFriend" placeholder="Name" required>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

if you need more code just let me know bum I'm very very confused because I just started using goorm and express and all of that

Comment: Wait so are just getting an empty string or an actual error when you console.log req.body.newItem?

Comment: whoops sorry my bad... it's empty string, not error

Comment: Do you have a body parser set up like => app.use(bodyParser.json())  or app.use(express.json()) ?

Comment: I have app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

Comment: I have the same settings as the other one but here it doesn't work and i have no idea why, if you want i can put everything on github so that you can take a look

Comment: Good Idea, link it to the question so other people can see too

Comment: there it is, check it out